# How to retrieve used_ids similar to a certain user_id with Twitter API v2?

Tags: api, twitter, twitterapi-python

When interacting with the Twitter with the UI, there is an option to retrieve similar accounts to the one being selected, e.g. if I am checking an account like @MacoubD Twitter suggests to me other similar accounts.

Is it possible to retrieve this list using Twitter API v2? I checked the docs but could not find the endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are no API functions that provide this in v1.1 or in v2.